# PHPUnit & Selenium - How to get driver being used by a test?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, driver

My general test setup looks something like:

```php
class MySeleniumTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase{

    public static $browsers = array(
        array(
            'name'    => 'Mozilla - Firefox',
            'browser' => '*firefox',
            'host'    => 'localhost',
            'port'    => 4444,
            'timeout' => 30000,
        ),
        array(
            'name'    => 'Google - Chrome',
            'browser' => '*googlechrome',
            'host'    => 'localhost',
            'port'    => 4444,
            'timeout' => 30000,
        )
    );

    //etc
}
```

And from here an individual test file looks something like:

```php
class MyTest extends MySeleniumTest{
    public function setUp(){
        parent::setUp();
        $this->setUser(1);
    }

    public function testPageTitle(){
        //Login and open the test page.
        $this->login(8);
        $this->open('/test/page');
        //Check the title.
        $this->assertTitle('Test Page');
    }
}
```

From here, when I run `MyTest.php` with PHPUnit, PHPUnit will automatically run each test case in `MyTest.php`. Furthermore, it runs each test on each of the specified browsers individually. What I want to be able to do is get information on the driver running a specific test case from within that test case. So something like:

```php
public function testPageTitle(){
    //Login and open the test page.
    $this->login(8);
    $this->open('/test/page');
    //Check the title.
    $this->assertTitle('Test Page');

    $driver = $this->getDriver();
    print($driver['browser']); //or something.
}
```

This however, does not work. And `$this->getDrivers()` just adds more drivers to the tests, and is only suppose to be used by the setup. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You should look at the source for it if you need to determine things like this. Try `$this->drivers[0]->getBrowser()`

Comment: @ColinMorelli: I was looking through the source. And I had looked at `$this->drivers`, however, doesn't this code just get me the first driver? The problem is I want to get the driver that's currently being used by the test. Any suggestion on how to get that working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `$this->drivers` is an array there is always only one element in it. You can check that [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php). So
`$this->drivers[0]` contains informations about currently running browser and you can use `$this->drivers[0]->getBrowser()` to output browser name.

Example:

```
require_once 'MySeleniumTest.php';

class MyTest extends MySeleniumTest{
    public function setUp(){
        parent::setUp();
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.google.com/');
    }

    public function testPageTitle(){
        $this->open('http://google.com');

        echo "{$this->drivers[0]->getBrowser()}\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.18 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.*firefox
.*googlechrome


Time: 7 seconds, Memory: 3.50Mb

OK (2 tests, 0 assertions)
```

Comment: Oh! I thought it just contained a list of drivers. Great.